# How to display div on click inside Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ussual modal window of Bootstrap and there I have a div which is hidden by default. I want to click on link (which is also inside this modal) and display it. Problem is that I could't make click on link and therefore my div still hedden.

Maybe someone had same problem or can give me good advice how to solve this task?

sorry that I did't post the code before I asked

```
<div class="modal fade js-custom-modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="f-item f-item-modal">
                    <!--./f-item__details-->
                    <div class="f-item__info">
                        <div class="f-item__head modal-view">content</div>
                        <div class="f-item__short _border">content</div>
                        <div class="f-item__requirements">content</div>
                        <div class="f-item__body">
                            <div class="f-item__dest">
                                <a href="#" class="display-route"><i><img src="....png" alt="route"></i>THIS MUST DISPLAY div.f-item__map</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f-item__map">
                            <iframe src="..." frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f-item__footer modal-view"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my jQuery code

```
$('a.display-route').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault;
$('.f-item__map').toggleClass('js-route');
```

});

at CSS

```
.js-route { display: block;}
```

Comment: please give us relevant code to your problem so we can assist. You can import your code using https://fiddle.jshell.net

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it. Please have a look.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.insidemodal").click(function(){
       $("div.abc").css("display","block");
    })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <a class="insidemodal">Some text in the modal.</a>
          
          <div class="abc" style="display:none">I am hidden unless clicked by an anchor</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried to do this at the same way, but I don't know why it did't worked for me

Comment: If it helped you, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give us more details. But classical problems here could be a delegation event problem with your link.

Ask you this question: Does your link exist at the moment you add the `on("click" ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    $('#div').css('display','block');
});
```

This is just an example. Its better if you can post your code here.